# Getting the last value of different time windows in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm working with a data frame that has multiple sequences in it.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(time=(1:15),value = runif(15,0,1),window=c("start","busy","busy","end",0,0,"start",
                                                           "end",0,"start","busy","end","start","end",0))

  time     value window
     1 0.2511834  start
     2 0.3024602   busy
     3 0.9286721   busy
     4 0.6067609    end
     5 0.4926921      0
     6 0.6618985      0
     7 0.9934828  start
     8 0.1178294    end
     9 0.2216256      0
   10 0.8140705  start
   11 0.1642058   busy
   12 0.3906732    end
   13 0.1873062  start
   14 0.8071036    end
   15 0.3448706      0
```

In the `window` column you see the different time windows/sequences. A window is from the `start` value till the `end` value and the `busy` values also counts.
Per window I need every value to be the same as the value it has in the end. So like this:

```
  time     value window
1     1 0.6067609  start
2     2 0.6067609   busy
3     3 0.6067609   busy
4     4 0.6067609    end
5     5 0.4926921      0
6     6 0.6618985      0
7     7 0.1178294  start
8     8 0.1178294    end
9     9 0.2216256      0
10   10 0.3906732   start
11   11 0.3906732    busy
12   12 0.3906732    end
13   13 0.8071036  start
14   14 0.8071036    end
15   15 0.3448706      0
```

if `window == 0`, the value can also be zero but I know how to do that.
Does anyone know an answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[window == "end", group := seq_len(.N)]
df[window != "0", group := nafill(group, "nocb")]
df[window != "0", value := last(value), by = group]
df[, group := NULL]
df[window == "0", value := 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(window == 'end', default = 0))) %>% 
   mutate(value =  if(all(c('start', 'end') %in% window)) 
     replace(value, match('start', window):n(), last(value)) else value) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
#    time value window
#  <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1 0.607 start 
# 2     2 0.607 busy  
# 3     3 0.607 busy  
# 4     4 0.607 end   
# 5     5 0.493 0     
# 6     6 0.662 0     
# 7     7 0.118 start 
# 8     8 0.118 end   
# 9     9 0.222 0     
#10    10 0.391 start 
#11    11 0.391 busy  
#12    12 0.391 end   
#13    13 0.807 start 
#14    14 0.807 end   
#15    15 0.345 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(time = 1:15, value = c(0.2511834, 0.3024602, 0.9286721, 
0.6067609, 0.4926921, 0.6618985, 0.9934828, 0.1178294, 0.2216256, 
0.8140705, 0.1642058, 0.3906732, 0.1873062, 0.8071036, 0.3448706
), window = c("start", "busy", "busy", "end", "0", "0", "start", 
"end", "0", "start", "busy", "end", "start", "end", "0")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: And this one as well! Thank you. A dplyr solution is always nice